# What is "one-stop memory corruption"?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, memory-leaks

I'm recently read a paper called *Exploiting the Hard-Working DWARF* on Hackito Ergo Sum 2011.
It contains the phrase "not a one-stop memory corruption". What is that?

Comment: For reference -  the presentation that uses the phrase in question: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/battleaxe/hackito_2011_oakley_bratus.pdf  and the actual paper about the technique: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/reports/TR2011-688.pdf

Comment: Also, "Hackito Ergo Sum 2011" is the event where the presentation was made, not the author.

Comment: Actually I saw the phrase in the first one. Thanks a lot for the second reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an exact term, but basically means something like directly overwriting a bookkeeping datastructure, such as the internal bookkeeping of `malloc`. "Not a one-stop memory corruption" would be an indirect corruption. This corruption will then cause a later innocent operation to corrupt memory.

In this particular case, the indirect corruption causes the DWARF exception handling code to corrupt memory.